# PHP/MYSQL Search rows for more then one occurance of substring (forwardslashes) and fix

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a series of unique urls in it, all of which contain leading http or https with the "://" in it. Some of the urls also have additional "//" with the string.

I have three problems I need to fix.

First, I need to find all rows with additional double forward slashes with the urls, without getting false positives from the leading http.

Second, I need to str_replace the "//" with "/" without effecting the leading "http://" and "https://" so I can UPDATE the row.

and third, delete the row if it is a duplicate because the row has already been INSERTed without the double forward slashes.

I do not know how to skip the first occurance of "//" in a MYSQL command... pretty sure I can solve the other two problems on my own if I can get past just finding the bad urls.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE `url` NOT LIKE 'http://' 
        OR NOT LIKE 'https://' AND LIKE '%//%'" ;
```

Comment: [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) might be of some use to you...

Comment: the double forwards are already in the database. So I'm looking for a way to identify them in the mysql. parse_url works before they are inserted, but kinda pointless to run through the entire db every update and check.

Comment: `WHERE url LIKE 'http://%//%' OR url LIKE 'https://%//%'`

Comment: AbraCadaver ----- wow, yet another example of over thinking it. I really have to stop doing that. Thank you so much, I'm an idiot.

Comment: AbraCadaver, please add this as an answer so I can vote it/accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `http://` OR `https://` that also has `//` somewhere in it

**OR**

Find NOT `http://` AND NOT `https://` that has `//` somewhere in it

---

```
WHERE
      (url LIKE 'http://%//%' OR url LIKE 'https://%//%')
   OR
      (url NOT LIKE 'http://%' AND url NOT LIKE 'https://%' AND url LIKE '%//%')
```

This will work for finding the rows but not replacing.

Comment: BTW I needed more % in the second line

Answer (score 0):

> First, I need to find all rows with additional double forward slashes with the urls, without getting false positives from the leading http.

Use the `LOCATE` method but start from the 7'th character in the string. This is after both `http://` and `https:/`

```
 LOCATE('//', `url`, 7) != 0
```

> Second, I need to str_replace the "//" with "/" without effecting the leading "http://" and "https://" so I can UPDATE the row.

First replace `://` with `:\/\/` and then do your replace. Afterwards revert `:\/\/` back.

```
 REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`url`,'://',':\/\/'),'//','/'),':\/\/','://')
```

> and third, delete the row if it is a duplicate because the row has already been INSERTed without the double forward slashes.

If you do not care which of the two records gets deleted. The easiest is to create a unique index that forces MySQL to drop duplicates.

```
 ALTER IGNORE TABLE `my_table` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `url`;
```

Note the use of *ignore* which tells MySQL not to trigger errors on duplicates.

You can then drop the index afterwards.

Comment: `ALTER IGNORE` was removed in MySQL 5.7.4.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL supports full regular expressions, so you can also match the `http(s)` prefix with this:

```
SELECT ... WHERE url RLIKE 'https?://.*//.*';
```